Cannot connect ssh unless i delete .vscode-server
I’m trying to connect to an SSH using the Remote SSH extension from VSCode on macOS. If the .vscode-server folder is removed before connecting, there are no issues, but if I connect without removing the folder, I always get the following error output :
[13:34:47.469] Log Level: 2
[13:34:47.473] VS Code version: 1.93.1
[13:34:47.473] Remote-SSH version: remote-ssh@0.114.3
[13:34:47.474] darwin arm64
[13:34:47.505] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+lxplus.cern.ch", attempt 1
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": true
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.useExecServer": true
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.useFlock": false
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": off
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.enableRemoteCommand": false
[13:34:47.505] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[13:34:47.506] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[13:34:47.506] "remote.SSH.permitPtyAllocation": false
[13:34:47.506] "remote.SSH.preferredLocalPortRange: undefined
[13:34:47.506] "remote.SSH.useCurlAndWgetConfigurationFiles: false
[13:34:47.511] SSH Resolver called for host: lxplus.cern.ch
[13:34:47.511] Setting up SSH remote "lxplus.cern.ch"
[13:34:47.512] Acquiring local install lock: /var/folders/rt/72c0n6gd3wld6hp5crbmwf280000gn/T/vscode-remote-ssh-47bf8c66-install.lock
[13:34:47.513] Looking for existing server data file at /Users/my_mac/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-47bf8c66-38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40-0.114.3-es/data.json
[13:34:47.513] No existing data file
[13:34:47.514] Using commit id "38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40" and quality "stable" for server
[13:34:47.515] Script variables:
 {
  "InstallExitCode.24": "AlreadyInProgress",
  "InstallExitCode.25": "ServerDownloadFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.26": "NoDownloaderAvailable",
  "InstallExitCode.27": "UnsupportedArch",
  "InstallExitCode.28": "StatusCheckFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.29": "NeedInsidersArch",
  "InstallExitCode.30": "NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck",
  "InstallExitCode.31": "ServerTransferFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.32": "ServerFailedToStart",
  "InstallExitCode.33": "NeedInsidersWindows",
  "InstallExitCode.34": "CreateInstallDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.35": "UnsupportedPlatform",
  "InstallExitCode.36": "ServerTerminatedCVE20201416",
  "InstallExitCode.37": "UnpackFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.38": "ChangeDirFailed",
  "InstallExitCode.AlreadyInProgress": "24",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerDownloadFailed": "25",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailable": "26",
  "InstallExitCode.NoDownloaderAvailableForStatusCheck": "30",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedArch": "27",
  "InstallExitCode.StatusCheckFailed": "28",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersArch": "29",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTransferFailed": "31",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerFailedToStart": "32",
  "InstallExitCode.NeedInsidersWindows": "33",
  "InstallExitCode.CreateInstallDirFailed": "34",
  "InstallExitCode.UnsupportedPlatform": "35",
  "InstallExitCode.ServerTerminatedCVE20201416": "36",
  "InstallExitCode.UnpackFailed": "37",
  "InstallExitCode.ChangeDirFailed": "38",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Success": "success",
  "InstallUnpackCode.Error": "error",
  "InstallUnpackCode.MissingFiles": "missingFiles",
  "uuid": "da30ed639cd0",
  "startMarker": "da30ed639cd0: running",
  "commitId": "38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40",
  "quality": "stable",
  "token": "111aaa1a-1a1a-1111-aaa1-11aaaa111111",
  "vscodeAgentFolder": "$HOME/.vscode-server",
  "allowClientDownload": "0",
  "forceClientDownload": "0",
  "cliNameInArchive": "code",
  "ignoreWgetConfigFlag": " --no-config ",
  "ignoreCurlConfigFlag": " --disable ",
  "wgetTriesSegment": "",
  "listenArgs": "--on-host=127.0.0.1 --on-port",
  "getDownloadServerStartTrigger": "da30ed639cd0:trigger_server_download",
  "getDownloadServerEndTrigger": "da30ed639cd0:trigger_server_download_end",
  "getProgressDownloading": "da30ed639cd0%%1%%",
  "getProgressInstalling": "da30ed639cd0%%2%%"
}
[13:34:47.516] Install and start server if needed
[13:34:47.518] PATH: /Applications/root_v6.32.04/bin:/usr/local/bin:/System/Cryptexes/App/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/local/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/bin:/var/run/com.apple.security.cryptexd/codex.system/bootstrap/usr/appleinternal/bin:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin
[13:34:47.518] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[13:34:47.524] > OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6

[13:34:47.526] askpass server listening on /var/folders/rt/72c0n6gd3wld6hp5crbmwf280000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-9d12f0528c2e4817d57e6b951b7b7813039fb82b.sock
[13:34:47.526] Spawning local server with {"serverId":1,"ipcHandlePath":"/var/folders/rt/72c0n6gd3wld6hp5crbmwf280000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-3180c3db80881db9f4075406323f5da54a89cf28.sock","sshCommand":"ssh","sshArgs":["-v","-T","-D","57734","-o","ConnectTimeout=1000","lxplus.cern.ch"],"serverDataFolderName":".vscode-server","dataFilePath":"/Users/my_mac/Library/Application Support/Code/User/globalStorage/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh/vscode-ssh-host-47bf8c66-38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40-0.114.3-es/data.json"}
[13:34:47.526] Local server env: {"SSH_AUTH_SOCK":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.VdGKbaBO0d/Listeners","SHELL":"/bin/zsh","DISPLAY":"/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.s4LyOLCq5R/org.xquartz:0","ELECTRON_RUN_AS_NODE":"1","SSH_ASKPASS":"/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/local-server/askpass.sh","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_NODE":"/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin)","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_EXTRA_ARGS":"","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_MAIN":"/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/askpass-main.js","VSCODE_SSH_ASKPASS_HANDLE":"/var/folders/rt/72c0n6gd3wld6hp5crbmwf280000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-9d12f0528c2e4817d57e6b951b7b7813039fb82b.sock"}
[13:34:47.527] Spawned 16806
[13:34:47.592] > local-server-1> Running ssh connection command: ssh -v -T -D 57734 -o ConnectTimeout=1000 lxplus.cern.ch
[13:34:47.595] > local-server-1> Spawned ssh, pid=16810
[13:34:47.596] stderr> OpenSSH_9.8p1, LibreSSL 3.3.6
[13:34:47.665] stderr> debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:xOtCWmpDSZenkpkC7zNvTW0l8eh3kXaStmqZC3UVcAk
[13:34:47.854] Got askpass request: {"request":" (my_ID@lxplus.cern.ch) Password: "}
[13:34:47.854] Showing password prompt
[13:34:47.855] Listening for interwindow password on /var/folders/rt/72c0n6gd3wld6hp5crbmwf280000gn/T/vscode-ssh-askpass-75695283b8817dcc32f04fc6c25070b9f05177de.sock
[13:34:47.855] Writing password prompt to globalState
[13:34:55.146] Got password response
[13:34:55.146] Interactor gave response: ********************
[13:34:55.147] Cleaning up other-window auth server
[13:34:55.236] stderr> Authenticated to lxplus.cern.ch ([188.185.22.153]:22) using "keyboard-interactive".
[13:34:55.726] > * ********************************************************************
> * Welcome to lxplus982.cern.ch, Red Hat Enterprise Linux release 9.4 (Plow)
> * Archive of news is available in /etc/motd-archive
> * Reminder: you have agreed to the CERN
> *   computing rules, in particular OC5. CERN implements
> *   the measures necessary to ensure compliance.
> *   https://cern.ch/ComputingRules
> * Puppet environment: production, Roger state: production
> * Foreman hostgroup: lxplus/nodes/login
> * Availability zone: cern-geneva-b
> * LXPLUS Public Login Service - http://lxplusdoc.web.cern.ch/
> * Please read LXPLUS Privacy Notice in http://cern.ch/go/TpV7
> * ********************************************************************
> * October 1st: Two AuthZ and AuthN Changes on LxPlus/LxTunnel
> *  https://cern.ch/otg0151290 and https://cern.ch/otg0150912
[13:34:57.211] > ready: da30ed639cd0
[13:34:57.223] > Linux 5.14.0-427.33.1.el9_4.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Fri Aug 16 10:56:24 EDT 2024
[13:34:57.224] Platform: linux
[13:34:57.234] > /bin/bash
[13:34:57.235] Parent Shell: bash
[13:34:57.235] Parent Shell pid: 16806
[13:34:57.246] > 2406889
[13:34:57.247] Waiting for pid of spawned 'sh' subshell: '2406889'...
[13:34:57.262] > da30ed639cd0: running
> Script executing under PID: 2406889
[13:34:57.280] > Found existing installation at /afs/cern.ch/user/a/my_ID/.vscode-server...
> Starting VS Code CLI...
> printenv:
[13:34:57.281] >     SHELL=/bin/bash
>     LBENV_ENTRYPOINT=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/LbEnv-stable.sh
>     LCG_RELEASES=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/lcg/releases
>     LHCBDOC=/eos/project/l/lhcbwebsites/www/projects
>     EOS_MGM_URL=root://eoslhcb.cern.ch
>     LCG_GFAL_INFOSYS=lcg-bdii.cern.ch:2170
>     HISTCONTROL=ignoredups
>     CASTOR_HOME=/castor/cern.ch/user/a/my_ID
>     EMACSDIR=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/lhcb/TOOLS/Tools/Emacs/pro
>     HOSTNAME=lxplus982.cern.ch
>     HISTSIZE=1000
>     OS_REGION_NAME=cern
>     OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID=default
>     GUESTFISH_OUTPUT=\e[0m
>     MYSITEROOT=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib
>     EDITOR=/bin/nano -w
>     KRB5CCNAME=FILE:/run/user/159775/krb5cc
>     PWD=/afs/cern.ch/user/a/my_ID
>     LOGNAME=my_ID
>     XDG_SESSION_TYPE=tty
>     MODULESHOME=/usr/share/Modules
>     MANPATH=/usr/share/man:/opt/puppetlabs/puppet/share/man
>     MESA_GLSL_CACHE_DIR=/run/user/159775
>     MYPROXY_SERVER=myproxy.cern.ch
>     X509_VOMS_DIR=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/etc/grid-security/vomsdir
>     OS_AUTH_URL=https://keystone.cern.ch/v3
>     GUESTFISH_RESTORE=\e[0m
>     MOTD_SHOWN=pam
>     LBTELEMETRY_ENABLED=x
>     __MODULES_SHARE_MANPATH=
>     STAGE_HOST=castorlhcb.cern.ch
>     HOME=/afs/cern.ch/user/a/my_ID
>     SSH_ASKPASS=/usr/libexec/openssh/gnome-ssh-askpass
>     LANG=en_US.UTF-8
>     X509_VOMSES=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/etc/grid-security/vomses
>     VIRTUAL_ENV_DISABLE_PROMPT=1
>     GUESTFISH_PS1=\[\e[1;32m\]><fs>\[\e[0;31m\] 
>     TMPDIR=/tmp/my_ID
>     CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/lhcb:/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/lcg/releases:/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/lcg/app/releases:/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/lcg/external:/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/contrib:/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/var/lib/LbEnv/3297/stable/linux-64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/LbDevTools/data/cmake
>     SSH_CONNECTION=134.158.153.61 57735 188.185.22.153 22
>     LBENV_PREFIX=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/var/lib/LbEnv/3297/stable/linux-64
>     LHCBRELEASES=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/lhcb
>     KUBECACHEDIR=/run/user/159775/kubecache
>     LBENV_SOURCED=2.2.2
>     XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
>     SELINUX_ROLE_REQUESTED=
>     LESSOPEN=||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
>     USER=my_ID
>     LCG_external_area=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/lcg/external
>     CONDA_SHLVL=0
>     MODULES_RUN_QUARANTINE=LD_LIBRARY_PATH LD_PRELOAD
>     OS_VOLUME_API_VERSION=3
>     LOADEDMODULES=
>     X509_CERT_DIR=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/etc/grid-security/certificates
>     SELINUX_USE_CURRENT_RANGE=
>     DISPLAY=localhost:21.0
>     LHCBDEV=/afs/cern.ch/lhcb/software/DEV
>     OS_IDENTITY_PROVIDER=sssd
>     SHLVL=2
>     LHCBNIGHTLIES=/cvmfs/lhcbdev.cern.ch/nightlies
>     LBENV_FLAVOUR=stable
>     GUESTFISH_INIT=\e[1;34m
>     CVS_RSH=ssh
>     LBENV_ALIASES=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/var/lib/LbEnv/3297/stable/linux-64/lib/python3.12/site-packages/LbEnv/data/aliases.sh
>     XDG_SESSION_ID=13607
>     OS_AUTH_TYPE=v3fedkerb
>     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/159775
>     OS_MUTUAL_AUTH=disabled
>     S_COLORS=auto
>     SSH_CLIENT=134.158.153.61 57735 22
>     __MODULES_LMINIT=module use --append /usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:module use --append /etc/modulefiles:module use --append /usr/share/modulefiles
>     OS_PROJECT_NAME=Personal my_ID
>     which_declare=declare -f
>     KDEDIRS=/usr
>     OS_PROTOCOL=kerberos
>     PATH=/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/bin/x86_64-el9:/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/bin/Linux-x86_64:/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/bin:/cvmfs/lhcb.cern.ch/lib/var/lib/LbEnv/3297/stable/linux-64/bin:/usr/sue/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/puppetlabs/bin:/afs/cern.ch/user/a/my_ID/.local/bin:/afs/cern.ch/user/a/my_ID/bin
>     SELINUX_LEVEL_REQUESTED=
>     MODULEPATH=/usr/share/Modules/modulefiles:/etc/modulefiles:/usr/share/modulefiles
>     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/159775/bus
>     LCG_hostos=x86_64-el9
>     MAIL=/var/spool/mail/my_ID
>     MESA_SHADER_CACHE_DIR=/run/user/159775
>     OS_COMPUTE_API_VERSION=2.72
>     OS_IDENTITY_API_VERSION=3
>     MODULES_CMD=/usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl
>     BASH_FUNC_ml%%=() {  module ml "$@"
>     }
>     BASH_FUNC_which%%=() {  ( alias;
>      eval ${which_declare} ) | /usr/bin/which --tty-only --read-alias --read-functions --show-tilde --show-dot $@
>     }
>     BASH_FUNC_module%%=() {  local _mlredir=0;
>      if [ -n "${MODULES_REDIRECT_OUTPUT+x}" ]; then
>      if [ "$MODULES_REDIRECT_OUTPUT" = '0' ]; then
>      _mlredir=0;
>      else
>      if [ "$MODULES_REDIRECT_OUTPUT" = '1' ]; then
>      _mlredir=1;
>      fi;
>      fi;
>      fi;
>      case " $@ " in 
>      *' --no-redirect '*)
>      _mlredir=0
>      ;;
>      *' --redirect '*)
>      _mlredir=1
>      ;;
>      esac;
>      if [ $_mlredir -eq 0 ]; then
>      _module_raw "$@";
>      else
>      _module_raw "$@" 2>&1;
>      fi
>     }
>     BASH_FUNC_scl%%=() {  if [ "$1" = "load" -o "$1" = "unload" ]; then
>      eval "module $@";
>      else
>      /usr/bin/scl "$@";
>      fi
>     }
>     BASH_FUNC__module_raw%%=() {  eval "$(/usr/bin/tclsh '/usr/share/Modules/libexec/modulecmd.tcl' bash "$@")";
>      _mlstatus=$?;
>      return $_mlstatus
>     }
>     _=/usr/bin/printenv
[13:34:57.284] > Removing old logfile at /afs/cern.ch/user/a/my_ID/.vscode-server/.cli.38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40.log
[13:34:57.292] > Spawned remote CLI: 2406907
[13:34:57.293] stderr> cat: /afs/cern.ch/user/a/my_ID/.vscode-server/.cli.38c31bc77e0dd6ae88a4e9cc93428cc27a56ba40.log: No such file or directory
[13:34:57.294] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.329] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.363] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.397] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.432] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.469] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.502] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.536] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.576] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.609] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.644] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.679] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.713] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.747] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.780] > Waiting for server log...
[13:34:57.814] > da30ed639cd0: start
> listeningOn====
> osReleaseId==rhel==
> arch==x86_64==
> vscodeArch==x64==
> bitness==64==
> tmpDir==/run/user/159775==
> platform==linux==
> unpackResult====
> didLocalDownload==0==
> downloadTime====
> installTime====
> serverStartTime==530==
> execServerToken==111aaa1a-1a1a-1111-aaa1-11aaaa111111==
> platformDownloadPath==cli-alpine-x64==
> da30ed639cd0: end
[13:34:57.814] Received install output: 
listeningOn====
osReleaseId==rhel==
arch==x86_64==
vscodeArch==x64==
bitness==64==
tmpDir==/run/user/159775==
platform==linux==
unpackResult====
didLocalDownload==0==
downloadTime====
installTime====
serverStartTime==530==
execServerToken==111aaa1a-1a1a-1111-aaa1-11aaaa111111==
platformDownloadPath==cli-alpine-x64==

[13:34:57.815] Failed to parse remote port from server output
[13:34:57.816] Terminating local server
[13:34:57.819] Resolver error: Error: 
    at v.Create (/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:501404)
    at t.handleInstallOutput (/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:498726)
    at e (/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:553052)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async /Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:575341
    at async t.withShowDetailsEvent (/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:579017)
    at async /Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:549757
    at async T (/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:547808)
    at async t.resolveWithLocalServer (/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:549297)
    at async k (/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:572473)
    at async t.resolve (/Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:576428)
    at async /Users/my_mac/.vscode/extensions/ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.114.3/out/extension.js:2:844803
[13:34:57.823] ------

I tried to put remote.SSH.useFlock to off, switch to pre-release version but it doesn't change anything
Edit : Removing the extensions.json file or the entire extensions directory prevent the SSH connection from failing. VSCode recreates the extensions part, and I’m in! But it is not viable...

In your .vscode-server there is config related cern.ch. cern.ch is not resolvable from your current network. Are you using anykind of VPN for private DNS server?

Thanks for the answer! But no VPN or private DNSserver...

Then you need to delete .vscode-server/bin

There is no bin dir or file in my .vscode-server
